# How to programatically find my friends Gps is switched on

Tags: android

i am writing a code for finding a friend's distance who is near to me using GPS. whenever i select to "find a friend", it should list out the names of my friends who is within 1 Km along with their distance from me. I am accessing my contacts list in which the names and phone numbers of my friends are saved.
Now am able to list the contacts name but the distance is displayed with similar value for all the contacts.
Actually i wanted to know how the GPS of my friends phone is detected by me.how to write the code for that.
 if anyone have any idea about this, please rely to this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: it will check state of gps of your phone not friend's

Comment: I was assuming that he would be writing an app that would run on his friends android as well, listening for location requests and replying to them. In that case this app would have to check whether the location can be retrieved at all. I don't think you can just get the location of people from your contact list.

Comment: Your point is exactly correct. but i want to locate my friends location from contact list of only those whose GPS is switched on in their phones.